# Pepper Robot out of Focus

Tags: pepper

Currently, I have worked with Pepper robot. I have long dialog and I wrote a concept about stop. Cause that Dialog a little bit long. When I write on Choregraphe console about stop concepts its working but when I say "stop " etc. it not working as I expect. What is solution about it?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "not working as I expect". What do you expect and what is actually happening. Please also provide the relevant part of the code. You may also want to check [ask].

Comment: It looks like the robot is not listening, which you can usually see with the blue, turning eyes. If the robot is not listening, it will ignore what you say, but you'll have to give more code to tell *why* it's not listening.

Comment: Thanks @Emile for response. Even if Pepper dont focus to me well I want I can interrupt while he says a long part of dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pepper can't listen while speaking, so basically you have no way of cancelling her speech by saying "stop" (which I understand is what you want to do).

Some solutions:

- Make your dialogue shorter! For example by editing out useless words, or splitting it in several parts with a pause / ask for "do you want to hear more?" etc. between parts.
- Add a non-dialogue way of interrupting the speech, such as touching the head or the tablet (especially the tablet, like a "next" button or something).

Comment: Can you share example program about interrupt dialogue best way*